# How to implement Callback Functionality in Wiremock?

Tags: wiremock

As per stated question my requirement is to do a POST call and then after getting the result `200 OK` for this call there should be an automatic subsequent GET call which will give the result after the some delay using [wiremock](/questions/tagged/wiremock).

So wiremock do have delay and proxying behavior but this scenario could not be achieved by using [wiremock](/questions/tagged/wiremock), as in [wiremock](/questions/tagged/wiremock) all the stubs are independent and provide individual or proxied response but could not provide the intermediate response followed by another call (callback).

Also on using proxy feature of [wiremock](/questions/tagged/wiremock) the url is automatically appended to the proxied URL which in not required in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Your first requirement might be satisfied using the webhooks extension: https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock-webhooks-extension

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i could not integrate the webhook extension with the standlone wiremock spring application. It gives error for no class found for which i have added the additional dependency but could not able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

In case of integration problem with https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock-webhooks-extension
Please also try this one: https://github.com/viniciusffj/wiremock-http-requests-maker
Second project works for us.

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are a great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)